# mypy cannot detect NameError/undefined variable/unresolved reference within a function

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I am new to mypy and just found a weird limitation that it cannot detect undefined local object reference within a function. For example:

```
def configure():
    undefined_obj.length = 10  # expect NameError: name 'undefined_car' is not defined

configure()
```

mypy happily reported that my code has 'no issue'

```
mypy test_mypy.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Am I missing some basic mypy configuration? pylint or PyCharm can easily spot this type of fundamental issue as "undefined variable/unresolved reference"

I thought mypy is better than pylint. That's why I'm try it but now I'm so confused and disappointed.

Comment: Mypy doesn't check unannotated functions by default.

Comment: "I thought mypy is better than pylint." - they're different things. pylint is a linter. mypy is a static type checker. pylint is a *bad* linter, but that doesn't make mypy a *better* linter, because mypy isn't a linter.

Comment: Thank you! how do I ask mypy to check unannotated functions? I compared pylint with mypy because they seems to help me detect runtime errors early. I know that's not all they can do. But for my requirement it seems pylint is easier to use:)

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#no-errors-reported-for-obviously-wrong-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which python static checker can catch 'forgotten await' problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894694/which-python-static-checker-can-catch-forgotten-await-problems)